# Hide header in tabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have this navigator, I want to hide the header only from component = {PagRoutes} (pagRoutes is a tabNavigator)
I appreciate any help

```
export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName='Login'
            >

            <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={PagRoutes}
                options={{ 
                    title: 'Dashboard'
                }}
            />

            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}
                options={{
                    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                    title: 'Login',
                }} />

            <Stack.Screen name="Registro" component={Registro}
                options={{
                    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
                    title: 'Registro',
                }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export default function PagRoutes() {
    return (

            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Exercicios" component={Exercicios} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give extra config to the `<Stack.Screen />`. You're looking for the option: `headerShown: none`. I'd do something like this:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={PagRoutes}
  options={{
    title: 'Dashboard',
    headerShown: none
  }}
/>
```

Comment: hello, thank you very much, just a correction, false instead of none. I should have read the options more calmly.